# Copy paste generates error: Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to copy/paste data which returns

> Subscript out of range

This code works in another workbook with different parameters.

```vb
'...
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:P" & lastRowCopy).Copy
activeWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & lastRowPaste).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'line where it breaks 'edited
wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

It opens a workbook "wb", copies the correct value (lastRowCopy & lastRowPaste are correct) and fails to paste it whereas activeWB is also set correctly since it is used before in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually used "sheet1" because it is the "genuine" name of the sheet which has been renamed.

```
activeWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")...
```

Changing it to the "changeable" sheet name worked.

So If I change the name of the tab again, my script won't work ?

thank you anyway.

Comment: Keep you sheet names current!

Answer (score 3):

rather than:

```
Range("A1" & lastRowPaste)
```

use:

```
Range("A" & lastRowPaste)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I keep having this error after turning A1 to A (which I agree is a mistake)

Comment: Before the Copy/Paste interrogate the usual suspects:  **MsgBox wb.Name & vbCrLf & activeWB.Name & vbCrLf & lastRowCopy & vbCrLf & lastRowPaste**